# Concatenate multiple fields where some contain null values (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, null, concatenation

In QGIS 3.18.  In a shapefile attribute table, I need to create a field that concatenates several other fields with a comma delimiter.  Some of those fields are NULL.

Currently my approach has been what I thought was the foolproof `"Field1"  || ', ' ||  "Field2" || ', ' ||  "Field3"`.  If all 3 of these fields contain a non-NULL value, there is no problem (example: Field1=A, Field2=B, Field3=C, result=A, B, C)

However, if one or more fields are NULL, the result is also NULL. (example: Field1=A, Field2=NULL, Field3=C, result=NULL).

I suspect there is a way to account for NULL values in the field calculator without resorting to Python. I do not believe that `concat` or `coalesce` can help me here, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Note: I'm not concerned with labels here, just attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. First possibility: use concat and replace double commas where you have empty entries:

   `replace( concat (field_a,', ',field_b,', ',field_c), ', ,', ',')`
2. Second possibility: use arrays to concatenate, they concatenate `NULL` values as empty strings that you can then remove. Use one of this expressions:

```
replace( array_to_string (array (field_a,field_b,field_c)),',,',',')
```

Or, alternatively:

```
array_to_string (array_remove_all (array (field_a,field_b,field_c),''))
```

[image]

Comment: It seems array expressions are the answer to nearly all of my questions  :)    Soon I will be an array expert.  Thanks @Babel.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility in case you want to concatenate all fields in your attribute table: `map_akeys( attributes( ))` gets the names of all attributes, `array_to_string` with delimiter `+` gets a string like `a+b+c` that you can than evaluate with `eval()` so that the actual contents of a, b and c are added:

```
eval (array_to_string (map_akeys( attributes( )), delimiter:='+'))
```

[image]